# Error 502 on wordpress after putting file with mail() function

Tags: wordpress, server

I have a wordpress website that was having problems sending forms from NinjaForms and Woocomerce notifications.

So, in order to test the mail() function, I added a new folder on the site called "test", and then a file called "index.php" with this code:

```
<?php mail('1231@gmail.com', 'Test', 'This is a test'); ?>
```

I couldn't even test this php file... because suddenly every time I try to enter to the main site I get:

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are
>   looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while
>   acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server,
>   it received an invalid response from the content server.

So... I deleted the "test" folder... (I know, it doesn't make any sense) but the error persist.

Is this coincidence? How can I solve this?

---

I'm aware that the server that host the website has cache problems, maybe this is related.

Comment: where you create a test folder, path?

Comment: the site (wordpress) is located on: {server}/site/wwwroot

I created the test folder right there, on that directory...

{server}/site/wwwroot/test

Comment: where you create a test folder ?

Comment: Using Filezilla, on "{server}/site/wwwroot"...

Comment: ok means you create a test folder on root. can you create again and give link of your site. so i can check that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120339/discussion-between-mollie-and-whitefloater).